# I am using elasticsearch-river, is there any way to index remote couchdb?

Tags: couchdb, elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a couchdb installed (1.2.1) and I want to implement search engine (elasticsearch)
but i want the search engine to be installed separately.
so i installed the elascticsearch and plugins (elasticsearch-river, elasticsearch-head) in differenct machine.
how can i create the index in remote db?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your CouchDB instance as remote using something like this when you PUT your river metadata:

```
"couchdb" : {
    "host" : "your.host.here.example.com",
    "port" : 5984,
    "db" : "my_db",
    "filter" : null
},
```

Check out the [CouchDB river README](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/blob/master/README.md) > there is info about configuring user name / password combinations and https.